# Best way to store and display images in Android

Tags: java, android, image, bitmap

I am developing an application which can edit images. At the start of my program the user sees a list of folders that contain images. Instead of showing default  folder icon i am showing an image from folder. I  have database where i store path to images and information about which image is displaying in the list near the folder name. Every time when my application starts it takes a  lot of time to load a scaled down image into memory and then display it, especially when there are a lot of folders with images and for each i need to load its icon. I have read this article http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html and every time when my app starts i am scaling down every image. 
May be the best way in this situation is to resize (not scale down) every image and then store it in the database? But i have read that this is not good. 
So i want to ask an advice of how to do in this case? And i also need an advice of how to optimize displaying images in the Android Galllery widget to make it scrolling more faster. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 Never store images in database. It is inefficient and slow.

2 There are several image loading libraries that solve the same problem. My favorites are [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)